# Spring response entity not working in browser but works in postman

Tags: java, angular, spring

I have created ExceptionHandler to handle file upload errors it looks like this
`   @ExceptionHandler(MultipartException.class)

```
public ResponseEntity<String> handleSizeLimitExceeded(MultipartException ex) {
    return ResponseEntity
            .status(HttpStatus.PAYLOAD_TOO_LARGE)
            .body("Exceeded file size");`
```

And my end point looks like this
`@PostMapping("add")

```
public ResponseEntity addFile(HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException, FileUploadException {
    fileService.addFile(request);
    return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
}`
```

The problem is when I'm using my rest api in postman I'm getting proper error message in case of invalid input but in browser when I do my request via angular I get
[image: unknown_error]

My Angular request code

```
 public uploadFile(files: any): Observable<any> {
    const uploadURL = '/server/rest/files/add';
    const req = new HttpRequest('POST', uploadURL, files, {
      reportProgress: true,
      responseType: 'json'
    });

    return this.http.request(req);
  }
```

Communication works from front to backend, I even get proper http codes for succesful request but in case of that custom error handler I get unknown error (I have been trying to change responseType in request but without much succes)

@Edit

I'm using angular proxy configuration if that does change anything (with cors enabled)

@Edit2

I have tried making sure that object returned will be represented in JSON

```
@ExceptionHandler(MultipartException.class)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.PAYLOAD_TOO_LARGE)
@ResponseBody
public FileResponse handleSizeLimitExceeded() {
    return new FileResponse()
            .setName("Test");
}
```

Which results in proper Json response on postman but same error on browser/angular

[image: anothererror]

Comment: I suspect that your exception handler is not returning valid JSON. Please verify in Postman that response is `"Exceeded file size"` and not `Exceeded file size` (please note missing `"` in the latter)

Comment: Tried to make sure that response is presented as json but it didn't work, still same error.

Comment: Is your `@ExceptionHandler` located in your `@Controller` ?

Comment: It is not, but it's getting picked up by component scan. I get proper error with postman request.